WiX 5 with .NET 8 CustomAction?
I have a WiX 4 project and it's referencing a CustomAction that is currently .NET Framework 4.8. I plan on upgrading the WiX project to WiX 5.0.0. Can I upgrade the CustomAction project to .NET 8 when I upgrade WiX? Or anything other than .NET Framework? I would like to stop requiring .NET 4.8 as a pre-requisite.

I hit the same wall ;-), limitation of WixToolset v5.
My workaround was:
Create a .NET 8 CLI (Command Line Tool, Console App with args / parameter handling), and call this tool from the custom action in .NET 4.8
Pseudo Code in WixToolset .NET 4.8 CustomAction
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult RunCommandLineTool(Session session)
{
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new()
    {
       // Define here your .NET 8 CLI program
       FileName = << PATH TO CLI v8 >>
       Arguments = << ARGS FOR CLI v8 (to execute the real custom action code) >>
       ...
    }
    using (Process process = Process.Start(psi))
    {
        ...
    }
    return ActionResult.Success;
}


Make sure that the CLI does (still) exist on the system. During installation CustomActions can only be called after "InstallFiles" Sequence. During uninstallation the CLI can only be called before "RemoveFiles". Or the CLI has to be places "somewhere" outside of the MSI folder structure.

With this workaround you can not go ahead without .NET 4.8, but a tleast you can limit the surface and need to write "old code".

With this method, you have to ensure that .NET 8 is installed before the custom action runs. I'm not sure that's worth making this change.

Dotnet 8 will be needed by your app anyhow, I assumed - sorry when I miss understood, so this can be installed may with the bootstrapper project. Your custom action can be called in the MSI project. Custom Actions are limited to .NET Framework (windows only). When this does not help. You can "try" to change your custom action to other programming language, this e.g. VBS will may cause other negative effects.
